# how to sort array of object in js by property i.ecategoryname' in my dataset in alphabetical order using mergesort

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

> Here is the list of data that should be sorted in alphabetical based of categoryName
> value using merger sort

```
    const filteritem = [
      {
        "categoryName": "admission",
        "rows": [
          {
            "uploaddate": "8/8/2022",
            "title": "binoddocs",
            "view": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
            "fullname": "bruno",
            "id": "B8QsXYVFH8fHt3PrBYUp"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "categoryName": "officialdocument",
        "rows":
          {
            "file": null,
            "uploadedby": "bruno",
            "uploaddate": "6/27/2022",
            "title": "sudhikchaadmission",
            "view": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
            "id": "Z27GLizWnYTJvLQyYRQt"
          },
          {
            "view": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
            "uploadedby":"bruno",
            "uploaddate":"6/27/2022",
            "title":"ankitadmission",
            "file":null,
            "id":"rmcbUrg9TpFhQh5RLqva"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "categoryName":"syallabus",
        "rows": [
          {
            "fullname":"bruno",
            "view":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
            "title":"sudhir",
            "uploaddate":"8/15/2022",
            "id":"hi7QEOlBzzVLZ1QHYqlk"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "categoryName":"Binodkhatricv",
        "rows": [
          {
            "title":"binodtry",
            "fullname":"bruno",
            "uploaddate":"8/15/2022",
            "view":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
            "id":"o4EtP1xkbWMk1icp4uNH"
          }
        ]
```

> i can use filter and includes method to sort.. but i have to implement some types of algorithm in my project like{mergersort ,bubblesort,depthsearch etc}but for now i need to use mergesort***
> The final result should be like this i have not included all the property inside the object here i think you got it ..

````
    filteritem=[
    {categoryName:"admission"...},
    {cateogryName:"Binodkhatricv"..},
    {categoryName:"officialdocument"...},
    {categoryName:"syallabus"...}
    ]```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` I guess it's do want to try to do :

```js
const filteritem = [
    {
      "categoryName": "admission",
      "rows": [
        {
          "uploaddate": "8/8/2022",
          "title": "binoddocs",
          "view": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
          "fullname": "bruno",
          "id": "B8QsXYVFH8fHt3PrBYUp"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "categoryName": "officialdocument",
      "rows":
        [{
          "file": null,
          "uploadedby": "bruno",
          "uploaddate": "6/27/2022",
          "title": "sudhikchaadmission",
          "view": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
          "id": "Z27GLizWnYTJvLQyYRQt"
        },
        {
          "view": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
          "uploadedby":"bruno",
          "uploaddate":"6/27/2022",
          "title":"ankitadmission",
          "file":null,
          "id":"rmcbUrg9TpFhQh5RLqva"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "categoryName":"syallabus",
      "rows": [
        {
          "fullname":"bruno",
          "view":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
          "title":"sudhir",
          "uploaddate":"8/15/2022",
          "id":"hi7QEOlBzzVLZ1QHYqlk"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "categoryName":"Binodkhatricv",
      "rows": [
        {
          "title":"binodtry",
          "fullname":"bruno",
          "uploaddate":"8/15/2022",
          "view":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
          "id":"o4EtP1xkbWMk1icp4uNH"
        }
      ]
    }];

    let sorted = filteritem.sort((a, b) => (a < b ? -1 : 1))
    console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `localeCompare` to sort the string, but after `toLowerCase` to ignore case sensitivity.

```js
const filteritem = [
  {
    "categoryName": "admission",
    "rows": [
      {
        "uploaddate": "8/8/2022",
        "title": "binoddocs",
        "view": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
        "fullname": "bruno",
        "id": "B8QsXYVFH8fHt3PrBYUp"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "officialdocument",
    "rows": [
      {
        "file": null,
        "uploadedby": "bruno",
        "uploaddate": "6/27/2022",
        "title": "sudhikchaadmission",
        "view": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
        "id": "Z27GLizWnYTJvLQyYRQt"
      },
      {
        "view": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
        "uploadedby":"bruno",
        "uploaddate":"6/27/2022",
        "title":"ankitadmission",
        "file":null,
        "id":"rmcbUrg9TpFhQh5RLqva"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryName":"syallabus",
    "rows": [
      {
        "fullname":"bruno",
        "view":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
        "title":"sudhir",
        "uploaddate":"8/15/2022",
        "id":"hi7QEOlBzzVLZ1QHYqlk"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryName":"Binodkhatricv",
    "rows": [
      {
        "title":"binodtry",
        "fullname":"bruno",
        "uploaddate":"8/15/2022",
        "view":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth",
        "id":"o4EtP1xkbWMk1icp4uNH"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const result = filteritem.sort((a, b) => a.categoryName.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.categoryName.toLowerCase()))

console.log(result)
```